# ReactJs Stop someone loading a page if someone is already inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am writing a system where multiple people will be logged into it at a time but we can't have two users looking at the same user record at the same time. how would i make it so that two people cant be looking at the same data. so say if username: admin is looking at record: 123, and username: user wants to access record: 123 user would be given a prompt saying "sorry admin is already looking at that record please wait until they have finished thank you"

how would i go about locking the other user out.

so you search for your record in the left box and click search it then brings up this results pane on the right with the results. i want it so when you click open it takes you to the record but if theres someone in the record i want it to say what i wrote above.

[image]

Comment: Give you show a brief description of what you've done?

Comment: I don't think it's related to react logic... If you are using backend as node js try with sockets and when user open a record change db value to open and manipulate with that.

Comment: @Rowland I updated it for you

Comment: I do agree, it is not react logic. You can't do such behaviour only at the client side. You should lock a user record at the server side (ex. db record).

At the client side I would make a router and every time when route changes I would check - if it is user record then lock it at the server side. When user lives that route I would remove locking sign from the db.

Comment: As some have mentioned, what you are looking for is a server side logic. you can do it with realtime frameworks (sockets.io / signalr etc..) or with pulling pattern from the database. in short, you must write a "manager service" that will manage and handle state across all clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way of achieving this, and you cannot do it client side as the browser is unaware of what is happening on other browsers.

You will have to implement something on your Server Side like [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

With the socket you can issue a websocket push to all currently logged in users when another user goes to a record.

> 1. For instance with your example lets say user Admin goes into record 123.
> 2. Then you can send a notification to all other currently logged in users and tell them user Admin is currently looking at record 123.
> 3. On the client side ( presuming you are using something like Redux for the store ) you can then update the records and make 123
>      unreadable or not displayable.

*There is something you need to keep in mind though, when the user navigates out of the screen you will need to unlock that record. The problem with that is that users can leave the page by doing multiple actions ( pressing browser back button, closing the page, or navigating to some other page on your application ). You will need a way to figure this out, once you have done so you can then update all users with a notification saying the record is now available and repeat the steps above.

Hope that explains it well enough, tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: Your steps are good, but I'd go one further and do not prevent anybody else from looking at or editing the records until the record they originally loaded is different that the one that's stored in the database. i.e. somebody else has edited and saved the record since you loaded it. You can envision that locking people out simply when someone is viewing a record is a bad idea (in the circumstance when somebody walks away from their computer for an hour or two with a record open on their screen, but they aren't actively doing anything to it).

Comment: That is a very good point. Although nobody should be able to view that record in this scenario as they can't access it while the other person is viewing it.

Comment: According the OPs specs yes, I was trying to make the point that the specs should be modified because this doesn't make sense. I've built this type of application before with these exact specs, making the record unavailable while somebody else is simply viewing it doesn't make sense. What if user A opens it for a readonly purpose (they just want to see the detailed information) while user B, who is now locked out, needed to actually make some edits and is now prevented from doing so?

Comment: Okay I'm following you now. I've also build something like this where inline editing is available to multiple users so if couple of them are editing something, the database will first check if the old value is the same as the current one and then proceed to do the write. I agree that it is a better approach but maybe his requirements are different. Never the less feel free to edit my Answer with that step in mind.

Comment: yeah but say if person A was doing a read only task and person B went onto the record and made a change person A's records would then be out of date so if they were sending an email to whoever the record is about it would then be invalid if they used the data so you couldnt have two people in the case at the same time. if that makes sense

Comment: You can also use the websocket to invoke a pull request in that case and make Person A's client side application make a get request for the new data. If you know that person A is sitting on that page and looking at the data then you can fire a message to them and make them request the new one.

Comment: you wouldn't want a page refreshing what if they were using the notes section on the page, if the page reloads it would cancel out what they were doing.

Comment: You are talking about them using a notes section on a page that is READ ONLY. Also if that is a problem you can always store that information on client side with react / localstorage.